# Is the SSH model a tight binding model?

Tags: condensed-matter, tight-binding

Sorry if this is an obvious question. I have trouble understanding where the Hamiltonian of the Su-Schrieffer-Heeger model comes from? May I confirm if it is from the Tight Binding Model? The creation and annihilation operators from the tight binding model seem to be expressed as bra-kets in the SSH model.

$$
\hat H 
=
\nu \sum_{m=1}^N\left(|m,B\rangle\langle m,A| + \mathrm{h.c.}\right)
+ w \sum_{m=1}^{N-1}\left(|m+1,A\rangle\langle m,B| + \mathrm{h.c.}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a tight-binding model but with two different hopping terms.